# Preventing silicon caulk from sticking to itself while creating tubes

Tags: caulking, caulk

Preventing silicon caulk from sticking to itself
[Food Grade RTV Silicone Sealant Adhesive Clear 10.3oz](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Food-Grade-RTV-Silicone-Sealant-Adhesive-Clear-10-3oz/281064707252?_trkparms=aid%3D1110012%26algo%3DSPLICE.SOIPOST%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20201210111451%26meid%3D9ebd4e397fef4d809177cef6957f4e9e%26pid%3D101196%26rk%3D2%26rkt%3D12%26mehot%3Dpf%26sd%3D283630411208%26itm%3D281064707252%26pmt%3D1%26noa%3D0%26pg%3D2047675%26algv%3DPromotedSellersOtherItemsV2WithMLRv3&_trksid=p2047675.c101196.m2219) when creating tubes.

Some videos show using hot water and some videos show using cold water and hydrogen peroxide [Video link on using silicone to create tubes](https://youtu.be/KlNXHEqKLdg).  Anyone know of a more exact formula / ratios most people seem to just be guessing.

**I'm not making a fuel line**

[image: image1]

**I'm not making a fuel line** but different size tubes which will be transporting **water vapour** / **mist** created using a ultrasonic transducer (used in pond foggers) to test with (testing a fogpoinc delivery system).

PS:  I know to use dark tubes to prevent algae growth in the tubes (this is just a delivery test setup).

I created / 3d printed different screw caps (extrusion molds) to create different size tubes to test with

Example extrusion mold below:

[image: Tube creator]

**Question:**

Anyone know of a more exact formula / ratios curing and preventing silicon caulk from sticking to itself while creating the tubes shown in the video.  The video shows using water and hydrogen peroxide but doesn't specify the ratios to use.

Comment: I am not sure why the down vote since no reason is given, I reversed one of them, if this is for diy home humidification I have seen it done in the past and it worked. If in a duct make sure to interlock with the blower so there will be air movement to take the moisture out of the duct into the home.

Comment: I'm not sure why they down voted it either I added images video and it deals with DIY and Caulk...

Comment: What is the reason for making tubing instead of buying off the self tubing?

Comment: @AlaskaMan cheaper for me to make them I'm making several different sizes to find the best fit.  Then I'll purchase the correct ones...Plus I like to learn new things...Hence the 3D printed extrusion mold.

Comment: you could smear silicone onto paper and roll into a tube

Comment: Have you posted the question on the video? The original uploader may well respond to tell you what worked for him.